# Boots to black screen with grub> but can only get exit to work AFTER many attempts

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I think I saw this before, but can't find it again. I am VERY new to Ubunut. I have a Toshiba Satellite w/12 GB Ram, Windows 10 and 500GB hdd. I installed 16.04 a while back and it worked fine for a while. Suddenly, when I start up my laptop, it doesn't boot all the way to the selection page - i.e. - Ubuntu, EFI, UEFI, etc. What shows on the screen is: 
                         GNU BRUB  version 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.2

Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported. For the first word, TAB lists possible command completions. Anywhere else TAB lists possible device or file completions.

grub>

When I try help it scrolls past so fast I miss at least half of the list. How do I stop/pause the scrolling to read what is in the help listing? How do I load the kernal or grub to get the system booted to the option screen? 
So far, the only thing I have been able to do is try "exit" until it finally boots to Windows. How do I get the option screen back and keep it there?
 I have tried to read up on this and would like to know if there is a guide to walk a newbie through the maize of DIFFERENT commands and verbage. This is so different from normal windows stuff, but reminds me of ms-dos yet is much more different it seems. help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to /boot/ partition is corrupt.
Try reinstall grub from livecd using command:
grub-install 
For example:
grub-install /dev/sda

Answer (score 0):

Your GRUB configuration file is probably missing or damaged. Try one of the following solutions, and if it fails, try the other:

- Boot an Ubuntu emergency disk (like the installer in "try before installing" mode) and run the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) tool from it. This should re-install GRUB and create a new GRUB configuration file. Note, however, that you must boot the emergency disk in the same mode (BIOS/CSM/legacy vs. EFI/UEFI) that you used to install Ubuntu, which in turn should be the same mode that Windows uses. This is *probably* EFI, especially if you're using a factory-installed Windows. If you installed both OSes yourself, all bets are off.
- Download the USB flash drive or CD-R version of my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html) and prepare a boot medium with it. You can then boot rEFInd, which should let you boot both Windows and Ubuntu. Test Windows, then reboot into Ubuntu. You can then install the rEFInd Debian package or PPA to make rEFInd the default boot manager on your system; or you can manually repair (and possibly re-install) the GRUB configuration. Note that rEFInd is an EFI-mode boot loader, so if you were using BIOS-mode booting, this isn't likely to work well. Also, if Secure Boot is enabled, you must either disable it or jump through extra hoops to get rEFInd working with it.